# sql MySQL error (1241) operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1241

first I will like to state that am still a newbie on writing SQL Queries. I thoroughly searched for an answer on this Error and I got a good number of answers, but none seems to be helpful or I will say I don't really know how to apply the solutions to mine.

Here is my challenge, I have an application table, that stores applicants records with some unique columns e.g (dl_number,parent_id,person_id). The parent_id keeps tracks of individual applicant history records with the his/her first record and each applicant is meant to have a unique dl_number, but for some reasons, some applicants dl_number(s) are not unique, hence a need to identify the records with changing dl_number(s).

Below is the SQL Query, that am getting the [sql error (1241) operand should contain 1 column(s)] error on.

```
SELECT id,application_id,dl_number,surname,firstname,othername,birth_date,status_id,expiry_date,person_id,COUNT(DISTINCT(dl_number,parent_id,birth_date)) AS NumOccurrences
FROM tbl_dl_application
WHERE status_id > 1
GROUP BY dl_number,parent_id,birth_date
HAVING NumOccurrences > 1
```

Please any help on how to solve this, or a better way to solve this.

[Sample table and expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUo6b.png)

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: You grouped by 2 fields and selected much more.

Comment: May be causing this `COUNT(DISTINCT(dl_number,parent_id,birth_date))`

Comment: You're group by is backwards... The other columns should be in the GROUP BY clause, those not arguments to aggregate functions. I.e. switch to `GROUP BY id, application_id, dl_number, surname, firstname, othername, birth_date, status_id, expiry_date, person_id`.

Comment: @ jarlh. Thanks for the quick response, I have added a sample table

Answer (score 0):

DISTICT is not really a function to be used that way.
You can do `SELECT DISTICT column1, column2 FROM table` to get unique rows only, or similarly `SELECT column, count(DISTINCT anothercolumn) FROM table GROUP BY column` to get unique rows within a group.

Problem as I understand it: You look for duplicates in your table. Duplicates are defined as having identical values of these 3 columns: `dl_n‌​umber`, `parent_id` and `birth‌​_date`.

I'm also assuming that `id` is a primary key in your table. If not, replace the `t2.id <> t.id` condition with one that uniquely identify your row.

If you only wanted to know what are the duplicated groups, this should work:

```
SELECT dl_n‌​umber, parent_id, birth‌​_date, count(*) as NumOccurences  -- You can only add aggregation functions here, not another column unless you group by it.
FROM tbl_dl_application t
WHERE status_id > 1 -- I don't know what this is but it should do no harm.
GROUP BY dl_n‌​umber, parent_id, birth‌​_date
HAVING count(*)>1
```

If, however, you want to know details of each duplicated row, this query will give you that:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_dl_application t
WHERE 
    status_id > 1 -- I don't know what this is but it should do no harm.
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM tbl_dl_application t2
        WHERE
            t2.dl_number = t.dl_number
            AND t2.parent_id = t.parent_id
            AND t2.birth_date = t.birth_date
            AND t2.id <> t.id
    )
ORDER BY dl_n‌​umber, parent_id, birth‌​_date, id;  -- So you have your duplicates nicely next to each other.
```

Please explain further if I misunderstood your objective, or ask if the solution is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
**You have to use only one column while use to DISTINCT function. You used this three field dl_number,parent_id,birth_date. Just use 1 filed from these 3. Then query will run.**
```

**For example.**

```
SELECT id,application_id,dl_number,surname,firstname,othername,birth_date,status_id,expiry_date,person_id,COUNT(DISTINCT(parent_id)) AS NumOccurrences
FROM tbl_dl_application
WHERE status_id > 1
GROUP BY dl_number,parent_id,birth_date
HAVING NumOccurrences > 1
```

Comment: Not true. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct